# Large C in SVM but it generalise well?

Tags: classification, svm, libsvm

I am doing a multi-class classification using SVM. I scaled my features to [0,1] and find the parameters C and gamma using grid search as suggested by LIBSVM guide. I use 10-fold cross validation for this.

However, the parameter I obtained was quite strange. C is very large (2^15).

At first I suspected that the model maybe overfit. I plot the graph between training/validation/test and it looked strange. The larger C, the lower error I got (this is expected). However, the different between training/validation/test is small all the way regardless different C (it suppose to be small when C is small and get larger as C increase, isn't it?).

So, I am not sure what is going on? Underfit? Overfit? or is it that there is something wrong with my data? Any thoughts?

Thank you guys!

Lucy

Comment: In what range are the accuracy numbers you get? if the data is easily separable, all cases might essentially be the same fit, with just tiny differences.

Answer (score 0):

The libsvm code for a grid search uses log2.  Are you sure that your C parameter, 2^15, is not really log2(2^15) = 15?